# How pass yield in method as param

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, block

I have method:

```
def return_dto_object(id)
    Comment.where(product_id: id)
end
```

And i wanna pass block and put it instead of `product_id`
For Example:

```
def return_dto_object(id)
    Comment.where(yield: id)
end

=> return_dto_object(1) { product_id }
=> return_dto_object(1) { id }
```

I just wanna change the column that the records will search for. This possible, that i want?

Comment: You can just pass that, what you want in the block as an argument. Is there a specific reason you want to use a block?

Comment: You have to deliver right away - `return_dto_object { Comment.where(product_id: id) }`??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`where` is able to receive a hash as an argument, so, whenever you do:

```
Comment.where(product_id: id)
```

It's equivalent to:

```
Comment.where({ product_id: id })
```

You can create a hash with "dynamic" keys the way:

```
{ key => value }
```

So, passing product_id, it'd be:

```
attribute = :product_id
{ attribute => 1 } # {:product_id=>1}
```

Which is the valid syntax for invoking `where`:

```
def return_dto_object(attribute, id)
  Comment.where(attribute => id)
end
```

If it's confusing, you can first create the hash, and pass it to where.